# What is a good simple text display widget and how to add borders to diffrent widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two questions regarding Tkinter:

1. What is a good simple text display widget that can output data too, and it will display it to the user without it being editable and also has a scroll bar if the text is too long.
2. In my program I have many widgets, I am interested in adding a border to them all. Is there an easy way I can do this?

Comment: 1) Text widget 2) Frame widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ScrolledText widget, and set the state of the widget to be disabled so it isn't editable. Without seeing your widgets it's hard to say... but you could pack each one in a frame to give each widget a "border" effect with the frame having a background color that would be displayed around the widget.

Edit: For inserting text / updating the widget you will need to toggle the state between `active` to insert and then back to disabled.

Here's a small random example of some widgets with a border and a scrolled text widget illustrating what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st
import random

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'green']

root = tk.Tk()
#Or set initial state to disabled and toggle state as needed for inserts
a_text_widget = st.ScrolledText(root)
for i in range(500):
    a_text_widget.insert("1.0", "Some Random Text Inserted Here")
a_text_widget['state'] = 'disabled'
a_text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
for i in range(10):
    a_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=random.choice(colors), padx=1, pady=1)
    tk.Label(a_frame, text='A Text Label').pack()
    a_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Going frames is one route, alternatively you can set the highlight color of the widget play around with root options for all widgets etc.